# Get related entites of child items using Linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have these entities:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerOrder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //Some other properties here...
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using Linq to get a customer and his orders as follows:

```
var customers = dataContext.Set<Customer>();

return (from customer in customers
        where customer.Id == id
        select new CustomerOrder
        {
          Id = id,
          Name = customer.Name,
          Orders = customer.Orders
        });
```

The above projects as expected. However, I need to retrieve the `Category` for each `Order`.

How can I do this by expanding the above Linq statement?

Comment: When `Orders` is `IEnumerable<Order>` and `Order` class has `Category` you will have `Category` of each `Order` in `Orders`; Your question is unclear to me! ;).

Comment: @shA.t It's null because it's not included in the statement.